# Rails: Uniqueness of two attributes in join table causing 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, join, validates-uniqueness-of

I have the following models, which basically are trying to mean that a **professor** has **knowledge** of many **subjects** for a particular **level**.  The subjects are fixed, so there will be no new subjects created, there will be just "related" to a professor through the knowledge join table.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Self Associations
  has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Subject"
  belongs_to :category, :class_name => "Subject",:foreign_key => "parent_id"

  # Associations
  has_many :knowledges
  has_many :professors, :through => :knowledges
end


class Professor < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  has_many :knowledges
  has_many :subjects, :through => :knowledges
  ...
end

class Knowledge < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :professor
  belongs_to :subject
  has_one :level

  attr_accessible :subject_id, :professor_id

  validates :subject_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :professor_id }
end
```

I want to have a form that will let a professor to add a subject to his account, and I decided to have a form for a knowledge (as I want to be able to insert a level too).

It looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @knowledge,:url => professor_knowledges_path, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <div class="control-group select optional">
      <%= label_tag "Subject Type", nil, :class => "select optional control-label"%>
      <div class="controls">
    <%= select_tag "Parent Subject", options_from_collection_for_select(@parent_subjects, "id", "name"), :id => "knowledge_parent_subject" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= f.input :subject_id, :collection => @subjects, :label => "Subject" %>
    <%= f.input :level %>
  <%= f.button :submit, t('add_form'),:class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

And in the **create** action of the Knowledges controller I have this:

```
def create
    @knowledge = Knowledge.create(:professor_id => current_professor.id, :subject_id => params[:knowledge][:subject_id]) 
  end
```

I would like/expect to get an **ActiveRecord** saying that this knowledge can't be inserted because there is a uniqueness violation, but nops, I just see a 500 in the logs and a rollback, but it seems the execution goes on.  So my question is:  What am I doing wrong, or how I could improve this modeling situation? I believe the form needs to be related to the join model as I want to have fields of that model on it...But maybe I am wrong, and I could do in an easy/cleaner way.

**EDIT**:

As asked in one of the comments, here is the log of the submission of the form and the 500 error right after the rollback:

```
Started POST "/professors/1/knowledges" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-01 00:45:39 -0700
Processing by KnowledgesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4JVyxWnIh37kyBwLwLGTHk/znsI1c5wrJvaWjKKT5tM=", "Parent Subject"=>"1", "knowledge"=>{"subject_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Añadir", "professor_id"=>"1"}
  Professor Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `professors`.* FROM `professors` WHERE `professors`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
```

I added some conditions in the **create** action, like this:

```
  def create
    @knowledge = Knowledge.new(:professor_id => current_professor.id, :subject_id => params[:knowledge][:subject_id]) 
    if @knowledge.save
      flash[:notice] = "Success..."
      redirect_to professor_path(current_professor)
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

And this actually shows the following right after the 500:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Subject has already been taken):
```

I wonder why the exception is raised instead of just adding the errors into the object and let me manage that situation.  Isn't what the following line should be doing?

```
validates :subject_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :professor_id }
```

Comment: Please post the logs that lead to 500. That would be helpful.

Comment: logs have been posted :)

Comment: Yes, the errors should've been added into the object. I don't think that is causing the 500 error. 
Can you halt the execution before `if @knowledge.save` line in KnowledgesController#create, using debugger or pry. Then try `@knowledge.save` and `@knowledge.save!` just to confirm the validation errors have been embedded into `@knowledge`. You could verify that even from the console.
Also, can you please post a gist of the entire stack trace. I've a strong feeling that this is not due to validating uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means you are trying to insert duplicate `subject_id` / `professor_id` pairs on that table. Most often happens when either the `subject_id` or `professor_id` is `null`.

Are you sure the controller is getting the correct parameters? I would check the logs to make sure the inserts are what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment...my answer is more some things to try than a definitive answer, sorry.

It looks like the save is failing due to validation errors. You can try to handle those in your 'else' block. The following will give you a description of all validation errors (useful for debugging).

```
@knowledge.errors.full_messages
```

You haven't shown what is happening in the 'new' action. I suspect this is where the errors are occurring.

Does the same issue occur (i.e. the validation problem) in the console? If so, try cleaning out your databases (beware - the following will erase & rebuild all your databases).

> rake db:drop:all db:create:all db:migrate db:test:prepare

Also, if you haven't already, add an index to your migration for Knowledge to prevent duplicates being added to the db. e.g.

```
    add_index :knowledges, [ :professor_id, :subject_id ], unique: true
```